# A small question: In vectors, is true that |w|+|v|=|w+v|?

Tags: vectors

A small question: In vectors, is true that |w|+|v|=|w+v|?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why vectors? It is not even true for real numbers.

Comment: $|1|+|2|=|1+2|$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: $|-1| + |1| = $...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not. Let $v$ be a nonzero vector, and $w=-v$. Then $|w|=|v|>0$ and $|w+v|=|0|=0$.

Answer (score 4):

In general, no.

A simple counterexample may be had by considering the vectors $\mathbf v = 3 \mathbf i$ and $ \mathbf w = 4 \mathbf j$ in the plane.  Then $\mathbf v + \mathbf w = 3\mathbf i + 4\mathbf j$; thus $\vert \mathbf v + \mathbf w \vert = \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5$, whereas $\vert \mathbf v \vert + \vert \mathbf w \vert = 7$.  In general we have $\vert \mathbf v + \mathbf w \vert \le \vert \mathbf v \vert + \vert \mathbf w \vert$ with equality holding if an only if $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ are collinear, that is, $\mathbf v = \alpha \mathbf w$ for some scalar $\alpha \ge 0$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: You need $\alpha\ge0$ in the collinear case.

Comment: @ lhf:  right you are!  Edited accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: The formal name of this is the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (also known as the Triangle Inequality - graph some sample vectors and you will see why a triangular analogy is appropriate)

Comment: @ Xoque:  I thought Cauchy-Schwartz was $\vert \langle v, w \rangle  \vert^2 \le \vert v \vert^2 \vert w \vert^2$.  I *do* know the name "triangle inequality" and *what* it names!

Answer (score 3):

[image]
$|w|+|v|=|w+v|$?
it's not true at all 
but it's true when two vectors have a right angle (90)

Comment: @ khosrotash:  nice, +1!  Love the graphic!